# Docusign REST API to get document in envelope

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, docusignapi

I am creating a MVC web application with Docusign REST API.
I am going to create actionlink in index view for each record witch downloads
document in the record's envelope.
I am planning to use call following HTTP request.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```

When I call this request, I get pop up where I can choose location and name of file for the document that I am downloading.

[image]

Is there any way for me to pass folder location and name of file as parameter and download the file without getting this pop up?
I don't think Docusign does not provide such API to download in this way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The pop-up has nothing to do with Docusign; rather, it's based on how you are downloading it. I would offer more but it's unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Web Server can not access the client's computer. Imagine if Google (or any other site) could just start programs on your machine when you visit their site! So popup has nothing to do with DocuSign.

So using DS API, you will get pdf as `byte[]`, once you got `byte[]` then its your code who has to write it to a File and that is not possible on a WEBServer as WebServer will not be able to access the CLient's computer to directly save them on the machine without showing that popup. If you run below code in Standalone Java Application or I think Java Applets can also do it, then you can use FileOutputStream to write `byte[]` into a file directly in the machine.